# Binding rabbitmq web mqtt plugin to loopback interface

Tags: rabbitmq

How to bind rabbitmq web mqtt plugin to loopback interface only?

I am trying to work with configuration file `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf`

```
listeners.tcp.1 = 127.0.0.1:5672
management.listener.ip = 127.0.0.1
management.listener.port = 15672
mqtt.listeners.tcp.1 = 127.0.0.1:1883

web_mqtt.tcp.ip=127.0.0.1
web_mqtt.tcp.port=15675
```

While configuration works fine for

```
AMQP (5672)
Management (15672) and 
mqtt (1883)
```

it fails for web_mqtt (15675).

```
$ journalctl -xe
{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,ranch_acceptors_sup,badarg}},
{child,undefined, {ranch_listener_sup,web_mqtt},
{ranch_listener_sup,start_link, [web_mqtt,10,ranch_tcp, [{connection_type,supervisor},{ip,"127.0.0.1"},{port,15675}],
rabbit_web_mqtt_connection_sup, Mar 20 16:32:07 visiongui rabbitmq-server[9069]:                   #{env =>
#{dispatch =>
{'_',[],
[{[<<"ws">>],[],rabbit_web_mqtt_handler,[]}]}]},
middlewares =>
[cowboy_router,rabbit_web_mqtt_middleware, cowboy_handler]}]},
permanent,infinity,supervisor,
[ranch_listener_sup]}}}},
[{rabbit_web_mqtt_app,mqtt_init,0,
[{file,"src/rabbit_web_mqtt_app.erl"},{line,65}]},
{rabbit_web_mqtt_app,start,2,
[{file,"src/rabbit_web_mqtt_app.erl"},{line,31}]},
{application_master,start_it_old,4,
 [{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,273}]}]}}}}}}
Log file(s) (may contain more information):
/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@visiongui.log
 /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@visiongui_upgrade.log
{"init terminating in do_boot",{could_not_start,rabbitmq_web_mqtt,{rabbitmq_web_mqtt,{bad_return,{{rabbit_web_mqtt_app,start,[normal,[]]},{'EXIT',{{badmatc
init terminating in do_boot ({could_not_start,rabbitmq_web_mqtt,{rabbitmq_web_mqtt,{bad_return,{{_},{_}}}}})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be a bug in how the `web_mqtt` settings are translated into Erlang terms. I have filed an issue [here](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-web-mqtt/issues/26) in case you'd like to follow along.

In the meantime, I suggest using a combination of `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf` and `/etc/rabbitmq/advanced.config` files in your environment.

`rabbitmq.conf` should have this content:

```
listeners.tcp.1 = 127.0.0.1:5672
management.listener.ip = 127.0.0.1
management.listener.port = 15672
mqtt.listeners.tcp.1 = 127.0.0.1:1883
```

`/etc/rabbitmq/advanced.config` should have this content:

```
[
    {rabbitmq_web_mqtt, [
        {tcp_config, [
            {ip, {127,0,0,1}},
            {port, 15675}
        ]}
    ]}
].
```

Please let me know if this resolves your issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for a quick solution and taking it up for proper resolution. It works now.